# JPA, Hibernate - handling ContraintViolationException wrapped into RollbackException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, exception

I'm having problem processing `ConstraintViolationException` and `RollbackException` in JPA2 / Hibernate / Guice environment. Both exceptions occur while bean validation, but:

`ConstraintViolationException` is thrown when I try to **persist** a new entity

`RollbackException` occurs when I'm trying to **merge** the entity into context

This happens while form processing (both creating and updating entities) and catching these exceptions is tiresome:

```
try {
    // service.method is annotated with @Transactional
    entity = service.create(formEntity);
} catch (RollbackException re) {
    // occurs while merging the entity
    if (re.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        errors.process((ConstraintViolationException) re.getCause());
    }
} catch (ConstraintViolationException cve) {
    // occurs while persisting the entity
    errors.process(cve);
}
```

I would not like to add another control flow and catching all `RuntimeException`s:

```
try {
    // bean validation fails (merge / persist)
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    if (errors.process(ex)) {
        // do something with entity
    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow force hibernate to not wrap CVE into RE? What is the most transparent and DRY way of processing and handling such exceptions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hibernate wraps all sql exceptions as a `RuntimeException` (feature of hibernate).. you are getting the `ConstraintViolationException` probably because there is some field which doesn't accept nulls and you are passing a null value at the time of insert.. (if you don't explicitly set the value of a pojo property its considered as null on insert)...

Comment: `ConstraintViolationException`s are wrapped into `RollbackException`s while merging, but they are not wrapped while persiting. To be specific, I have set constraint `@Size(min=1, message="Must consist of at least 1 character")` which is validated and thrown exceptions are expected behavior when constraints are not met..